# Nexus 3 Docker container and Backup

Tags: docker, backup, nexus3, n3dr

I'm testing Nexus 3 from Docker container and I'm using https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus/blob/94d654faa2166b60fe2a4ad9629ff418a305dcb9/oss/Dockerfile.

The issue is that when I upload artifact to the Nexus I cant find it in the file system in order to create backup.
The folder /sonatype-work is empty. I've successfully use this approach for backup of Nexus 2.

Could you please advice me where Nexus 3 stores its artifacts.

Comment: The sonatype-work folder no longer seems to exist in Nexus 3. The best answer I could find is from the mailing list. https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/d/msg/nexus-users/zKfAG63KJZ0/WMQN7ovuAwAJ
Guess I won't be upgrading any time soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nexus 3 backup via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272210/nexus-3-backup-via-command-line)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to backup all Nexus 3 artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467106/how-to-backup-all-nexus-3-artifacts)

Comment: It does exists and can be deducted from the behaviour of the Dockerfile. 
The new replacement for that location is: 

/opt/sonatype/sonatype-work

Answer (score 0):

Try the helicopterizer for Backup and Restore for Docker Container in the Cloud Providers.

https://github.com/frekele/helicopterizer

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the installation instructions, you should have a volume mount of nexus-data. You can find this by executing the following from the docker host (assuming the volume name is nexus-data):

```
# docker inspect nexus-data
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/some/dir/nexus-data/_data",
        "Name": "nexus-data",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

This is the host dir that you will need to use for your backup script.