# How to backup all Nexus 3 artifacts?

Tags: maven, orientdb, nexus3, n3dr

I was wondering how to download all (not one or two specified ones) artifacts from a Nexus 3 repo to local disk. In Nexus 2 it was easy since everything was stored on disk and I would just rsync all the artifacts to my local disk.

But in Nexus 3 all artifacts are stored in the OrientDB and I will have to take an other route. I was thinking about downloading them per http after getting a complete list somehow.

Does anybody has an idea on how to perform such an export?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: There are some available options, see here: https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/#!topic/nexus-users/xdsKXeveUL0

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to migrate to another Artifact Repository Manager

Comment: "But in Nexus 3 all artifacts are stored in the OrientDB and I will have to take an other route. I was thinking about downloading them per http after getting a complete list somehow." 
I was thinking about that all along, but how would I do that?

Comment: There is no rest api to get a list of all paths or artifacts. Where would i get this list from? I saw the maven indexer referenced somewhere, but no documentation for it.

Comment: After searching a little bit: https://github.com/nongfenqi/nexus3-rundeck-plugin

Comment: @khmarbaise [n3dr](https://github.com/030/n3dr) is able to download all artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified following groovy scirpt, which can be uploaded using the API: https://gist.github.com/kellyrob99/2d1483828c5de0e41732327ded3ab224

To upload and execute the script I took a look at the examples: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x

Answer (score 5):

One could download all artifacts from a Nexus3 repository by using [n3dr](https://github.com/030/nexus3-cli).

Comment: I used it, it works very well to download and upload.

Comment: I used the below command.
"n3dr backup -u admin -p xxxxxx -n https://nexus-url.cloud -r app-releases --directory-prefix /home/nexus/revamp_bkp -d"

I am getting this error.
FATA[0000]/home/runner/work/n3dr/n3dr/cmd/n3dr/backup.go:42 main.glob..func1() HTTPS://nexus-url.cloud:443/repository/app-releases/com/abc/def/xyz/0.0.2/app-api-definition-0.0.2.jar is not an URL

Can some one help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you create an issue in https://github.com/030/n3dr?

Comment: @VineethNG We use a regex to check the URL. Did you either specify http:// or https:// as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the version upgrade on the Dockerfile they have modified the location for the base app.
You need to point your storage to

```
/opt/sonatype/sonatype-work
```

Source: https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

I had to do move all artifacts from one Nexus 3 repository to another one. Once this was accidental, I developed the procedure (Windows):

- from Nexus' web interface / Browse / Assets took the JSON with the list of assets
- extracted the assets' URLs by collecting the values of their "name" attribute
- delete all assets that are .md5, .sha1, maven-metadata.xml
- delete all assets that are pom.xml for another atrifact
- split the artifact URLS into

  ```
  path in the repository - it is in the format /&lt;groupId path>/&lt;artifactId>/&lt;versionId>/&lt;file name>
  groupId- parse the path, replacing / with .
  artifactId - parse the path,
  version - parse the path, 
  file name - parse the path
  packaging - the file name extension
  ```
- for each such parsed URL call the script (named publish.bat):

  ```
  @echo off
  rem %1 = from repository URL
  rem %2 = to repository URL
  rem %3 = path
  rem %4 = groupId
  rem %5 = artifactId
  rem %6 = version
  rem %7 = file name
  rem %8 = packaging
  echo.
  echo %1%3/%5/%6/%7
  echo.

  curl --remote-name --create-dirs --output %7 %1%3/%5/%6/%7

  call mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%4 -DartifactId=%5 -Dversion=%6 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=%8 -DrepositoryId=admin -Durl=%2 -Dfile=%7

  del %7
  ```

NOTE: -DrepositoryId=admin is a reference to a server definition in the Maven's settings.xml defining the user and password to publish in the target repository.

Example:

```
set FROM=source repository URL
set TO=target repository URL

call publish.bat %FROM% %TO% net/xyz/webtools net.xyz.webtools buildServer 03.06.00.01 buildServer-03.06.00.01.war war
```

Answer (score -3):

You can retrieve all DownloadURLs using the REST-API, then download them all. I did this with a simple Python Script.

Comment: Could you share this script?

Comment: This is the most useless answer I've ever seen. If you want to help then explain in details , otherwise spare us the useless characters.