# Nexus Repository 3 backup

Tags: backup, database-backups, nexus3, backup-strategies, n3dr

Recently I installed **Nexus Repository 3** in OpenStack Cloud and I am using it for a while now. I would like to perform incremental backup of Nexus and thus securing our data.

**How can one perform incremental backups of nexus data?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to backup all Nexus 3 artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467106/how-to-backup-all-nexus-3-artifacts)

Answer (score 3):

The procedure for Nexus backup is described in [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=5412146#content/view/5412146).

Nexus provides the scheduled task `Export configuration & metadata for backup` out of the box. However this task takes care only of backing up the underlaying Orient DB.

You must still assure that you back up your Nexus `${data_dir}` around the same time you run the mentioned scheduled task. The same goes for your blob stores. Preferably during off-office hours. Notice that DB stores pointers to the blob stores.

The easiest way is to do the classic backup. If your goal is to perform incremental backup than I assume you will have to choose some strategy for discovering **altered files**. Perhaps based on file timestamp and thus backing up only those.

Please bear in mind my assumption above may be wrong. I wanted to point out just my idea on how to solve your problem.