# Nexus 3 Backups - Can I just backup /nexus-data?

Tags: backup, nexus, sonatype, nexus3, n3dr

I'm using the docker container to run Nexus 3.

If I stop the container, then backup the volume directory for `/nexus-data` will this result in a valid backup?

Just want to confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to backup all Nexus 3 artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467106/how-to-backup-all-nexus-3-artifacts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine, you can directly back up the entire work directory if Nexus is not running.