# Move Old Artefacts from one nexus repository to Another Nexus repository

Tags: groovy, nexus3, n3dr

How to migrate the Artefacts which are older than 90 days to another nexus server?

I can able to delete the artefacts older than 90 days from Nexus3, but the requirement is to take backup of old artefacts to another nexus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nexus 3 backup via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272210/nexus-3-backup-via-command-line)

Comment: You could use [n3dr](https://github.com/030/n3dr)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to backup all Nexus 3 artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467106/how-to-backup-all-nexus-3-artifacts)